# Generate Pre-signed URL in PHP for Contabo

Tags: php

I'm trying to generate a presigned url since I don't want to make my bucket completely public.
I'm using contabo with your Object Storage system.
https://docs.contabo.com/docs/products/Object-Storage/HowTo/presigned-url

Now, the problem is that the documentation they have does not make it completely clear to me, unfortunately I have not signed the url manually before, Obviously I have used the AWS SDK to sign the URLs automatically.
I also found this function in PHP but it turns out that it only works for AWS

https://gist.github.com/kelvinmo/d78be66c4f36415a6b80

However, when I use the program recommended by them, which is Cyberduck, if it generates it correctly, call them pre-signed, but of course, it is an external program to the programming that I am trying to create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix it using this guide.
https://docs.medianova.com/using-pre-signed-url-php-with-stook/

in the following way

```
$s3Client = new S3Client([
    'endpoint' => 'https://usc1.contabostorage.com',
    'use_path_style_endpoint' => true,
    'version' => 'latest', 'region' => 'usc1', 'credentials' => ['key' => 'xxxxx', 'secret' => 'xxxx']
]);

$cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('GetObject', ['Bucket' => 'bucketxxxx', 'Key' => 'path/to/file']);

$request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+120 minutes');

$presignedUrl = (string)$request->getUri();
```

Using the amazon SDK.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-presigned-url.html